# phonegap gallery upload image

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm trying to get an image from the gallery, but it does not work

The error I get from the below code is:

> Upload failed: Code = 3

Upload Image

```
function uploadPicture() {  
    // Get URI of picture to upload
    var img = document.getElementById('camera_image');
    var imageURI = img.src;
    if (!imageURI || (img.style.display == "none")) {
        document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Take picture or select picture from library first.";
        return;
    }

    // Verify server has been entered
    server = document.getElementById('serverUrl').value;

    if (server) {       
        // Specify transfer options
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
        options.chunkedMode = false;
        options.headers = {
           Connection: "close"
        };
        // Transfer picture to server
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, server, function(r) {
            document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Upload successful: "+r.bytesSent+" bytes uploaded.";              
        }, function(error) {
            document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Upload failed: Code = "+error.code;               
        }, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the plugin code, I see this: "public static int CONNECTION_ERR = 3;" - you're certain your server parameter is correct?

Comment: Yes, because I use the camera it works great! 
I've used this code: https://github.com/brycecurtis/articles/blob/master/CameraUpload/Android/assets/www/index.html

Comment: I have the exact same logic working just fine on my phonegap application, we are looking at a server-side problem here ;)

Edit: Try trimming the file extension out of the name, it is the only thing different from my setup